# Iterating through form data

Tags: python, django

I have a QueryDict object in Django as follows:

```
{'ratingname': ['Beginner', 'Professional'], 'sportname': ['2', '3']
```

where the mapping is such:

```
2 Beginner
3 Professional
```

and 2, 3 are the primary key values of the sport table in `models.py`:

```
class Sport(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)

class SomeTable(models.Model):
    sport = models.ForeignKey(Sport)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

My question here is, how do I iterate through `ratingname` such that I can save it as

```
st = SomeTable(sport=sportValue, rating=ratingValue)
st.save()
```

I have tried the following:

```
ratings = dict['ratingname']
sports = dict['sportname']
for s,i in enumerate(sports):
    sport = Sport.objects.get(pk=sports[int(s[1])])
    rate = SomeTable(sport=sport, rating=ratings[int(s)])
    rate.save()
```

However, this creates a wrong entry in the tables. For example, with the above given values it creates the following object in my table:

```
id: 1
sport: 2
rating: 'g'
```

How do I solve this issue or is there a better way to do something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. The main one is that `QueryDict`s return only the last value when accessed with `['sportname']` or the like. To get the list of values, use `getlist('sportname')`, as documented here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist

Your `enumerate` is off, too - `enumerate` yields the index first, which your code assigns to `s`. So `s[1]` will throw an exception. There's a better way to iterate through two sequences in step, though - `zip`.

```
ratings = query_dict.getlist('ratingname') # don't reuse built in names like dict
sports = query_dict.getlist('sportname')
for rating, sport_pk in zip(ratings, sports):
    sport = Sport.objects.get(pk=int(sport_pk))
    rate = SomeTable(sport=sport, rating=rating)
    rate.save()
```

You could also look into using a `ModelForm` based on your `SomeTable` model.

Comment: Thanks, Peter! The explanation helped a lot. I had no idea where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `zip`:

```
ratings = dict['ratingname']
sports = dict['sportname']
for rating, sport_id in zip(ratings, sports):
    sport = Sport.objects.get(pk=int(sport_id))
    rate = SomeTable(sport=sport, rating=rating)
    rate.save()
```